# PLSQL Problem for checking if cursor ISOPEN

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

What I am trying to achieve is to check if the cursor is open or not as a safety precaution but I always get this error. Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
29/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
29/5     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'WROTE_CUR'

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_publication (p_name CHAR) AS

CURSOR wrote_cur (v_AID NUMBER) IS
 SELECT AID,PUBID FROM wrote WHERE AID = v_AID;

 v_wrote_rec wrote_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

IF NOT wrote_cur%ISOPEN THEN
OPEN wrote_cur;
END IF;


 CLOSE wrote_cur;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared cursor with an input `Argument`.

```
CURSOR wrote_cur (v_AID NUMBER) IS --<-- Cursor is expecting argument at runtime
```

While in the Begin block you are not passing any argument to the cursor.

```
 OPEN wrote_cur; --<-- Here..
```

pass the argument like:

```
 OPEN wrote_cur(1);
```

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mistake : Forgot to pass an argument

```
  IF NOT wrote_cur%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN wrote_cur (v_author_ID);
  END IF;
```